If a quasi-coherent sheaf is zero when restricted to each fibre then is it zero?
Let $A$ be a ring and $M$ an $A$-module. Suppose for every field $k$ with a ring map $A \rightarrow k$ the module $M \otimes_A k = 0$. Can we conclude $M=0$?

Please don't change your question in such a way that it invalidates an existing answer. Instead, please post a new question with the correct hypotheses. See here on Meta for our policies about this.

Ah my bad. Thanks for letting me know.

No, we can’t.
Consider the module $M=\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ as a $A=\mathbb{Z}_p$-module. Then $M=pM$, so $M \otimes \mathbb{F}_p=0$. But $M$ is torsion, so $M \otimes \mathbb{Q}_p=0$.
Note that any morphism $\mathbb{Z}_p \rightarrow k$ for a field $k$ factors through $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Btw, your answer ends mid-sentence.

@red_trumpet: my bad, thank you!

Thank you, that is a wonderful counterexample. However, if I require that the $\mathrm{\textbf{derived}}$ restriction to each fibre be zero (i.e. $M \otimes^L_A k = 0$ for every $A \rightarrow k$), does that change the outcome?

@Calculus101: I do not know. This certainly works when $R$ is a PID (because the derived tensor product controls $Tor_1$, which describes torsion), and therefore when $R$ is Dedekind. We can probably assume that $R$ is local, and I suppose the next step is to check what happens for $R$ local regular of dimension $2$…
